# Returning/Passing an dynamically allocated object by Reference

Tags: c++, return-by-reference

I have this issue right now in my Abstract Data Type. Basically it is supposed to be like the string class normally in c++ so don't get confused by the numbers in my ADT. 
I am having the issue on creating a dynamically allocated object. (Which I believe implemented correctly in the code below) Then I need to call the `concat` function that has a reference to a `String346` object.

Also in this code I am supposed to return a reference. If someone could explain this concept to me on how this would be used and how I would return it the correct way please let me know because I return a reference to `String346` in many of my functions.

Here is the overloaded/default constructor (data is a `char *` and `size` is an `unsigned int`):

```
String346::String346(const char * oldString = "") : size(strlen(oldString)) {
        strcpy(data, oldString);
    }
```

Here is my code for my `concat` function for a `String346` object being passed in (Don't have anything written because I haven't got to the planning on how I want to do this):

```
String346 & String346::concat(const String346 & catString){

    }
```

Here is where I am getting confused. This is my `concat` function using a `char` pointer. The current segment `concat(&newCatString);` is wrong and doesn't work with the above function.:

```
    String346 & String346::concat(const char * catString){
    String346 * newCatString = new (std::nothrow) String346(catString);
    concat(&newCatString);
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else. I believe this is what you need you shouldn't need to know much more.

Comment: `concat(&newCatString);` passes the address of the pointer variable.

Comment: Ok. If I don't add the `&` it still gives me the error saying there is no function that accepts this argument.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] to demonstrate your problems.

Comment: I don't know what confuses you. This is my just explaining what I have a question over. I have posted the necessary code to what most people need.

Comment: You need to pass a `Foo` to a function that accepts a `Foo` reference.  If you currently have a `Foo*`, you get a `Foo` by dereferencing it: `*foo`.

Comment: @Donnie Thanks that got rid of the error that I am getting when passing the object in! Do I do the same thing for returning the reference?

Comment: if you return a reference that's actually dynamically allocated on the heap you completely hide that fact to the caller, which means that most likely you'll be leaking memory like crazy.  Don't overuse references.  Sometimes, a hammer is the wrong tool.

Comment: If `data` is `char *data;` then `strcpy(data, oldString)` writes to an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about this the wrong way.  You don't dynamically allocate a new object.  You dynamically (re)allocate the data of the object that is being assigned/concatenated to, and then return a reference to that object, not a reference to a new allocated object.

If you really want to implement this manually in a string-like class (instead of using the standard `std::string` class), then try something more like this:

```
class String346 {
private:
    char *data;
    unsigned int size;

public:
    String346();
    String346(const char *oldString);
    String346(const String346 &oldString);
    ~String346();

    //...

    String346& operator=(const String346 &newString);

    //...

    String346& concat(const String346 &catString);

    //...
};
```

```
String346::String346() : data(NULL), size(0) {
}

String346::String346(const char * oldString) : data(NULL), size(std::strlen(oldString)) {
    data = new char[size+1];
    std::copy_n(oldString, size, data);
    data[size] = 0;
}

String346::String346(const String346 &oldString) : data(NULL), size(oldString.size) {
    data = new char[size+1];
    std::copy_n(oldString.data, size, data);
    data[size] = 0;
}

String346::~String346() {
    delete[] data;
}

String346& operator=(const String346 &newString) {
    String346 tmp(newString);
    std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    size = tmp.size;
    return *this;
}

String346 & String346::concat(const String346 &catString) {
    String346 tmp;
    tmp.size = size + catString.size;
    tmp.data = new char[tmp.size+1];
    std::copy_n(data, size, tmp.data);
    std::copy_n(catString.data, catString.size, tmp.data+size);
    tmp.data[tmp.size] = 0;
    std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    size = tmp.size;
    return *this;
}
```

Technically, you do not have to implement a `char*` version of either `operator=()` or `concat()` since they both take `const String346&` as input and `String346` has a constructor that accepts a `char*` as input.  If you pass a `char*` to one of them, the compiler will automatically construct and destruct a temporary `String346` object for you:

```
String346 s;
s = "hello"; // calls s.operator=(String346("hello"))...
s.concat("world"); // calls s.concat(String346("world"))...
```

Though, for optimization purposes, it might make sense to do so, to avoid unnecessary allocations of temporary memory (unless you implement move semantics in C++11):

```
class String346 {
private:
    char *data;
    unsigned int size;

public:
    String346();
    String346(const char *oldString);
    String346(const String346 &oldString);
    ~String346();

    //...

    String346& operator=(const char *newString);
    String346& operator=(const String346 &newString);

    //...

    String346& concat(const char *catString);
    String346& concat(const String346 &catString);

    //...
};
```

```
String346::String346() : data(NULL), size(0) {
}

String346::String346(const char * oldString) : data(NULL), size(std::strlen(oldString)) {
    data = new char[size+1];
    std::copy_n(oldString, size, data);
    data[size] = 0;
}

String346::String346(const String346 &oldString) : data(NULL), size(oldString.size) {
    data = new char[size+1];
    std::copy_n(oldString.data, size, data);
    data[size] = 0;
}

String346::~String346() {
    delete[] data;
}

String346& operator=(const char *newString) {
    String346 tmp(newString);
    std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    size = tmp.size;
    return *this;
}

String346& operator=(const String346 &newString) {
    String346 tmp(newString);
    std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    size = tmp.size;
    return *this;
}

String346 & String346::concat(const char *catString) {
    unsigned int catSize = std::strlen(catString);
    String tmp;
    tmp.size = size + catSize;
    tmp.data = new char[tmp.size+1];
    std::copy_n(data, size, tmp.data);
    std::copy_n(catString, catSize, tmp.data+size);
    tmp.data[tmp.size] = 0;
    std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    size = tmp.size;
    return *this;
}

String346 & String346::concat(const String346 & catString) {
    String tmp;
    tmp.size = size + catString.size;
    tmp.data = new char[tmp.size+1];
    std::copy_n(data, size, tmp.data);
    std::copy_n(catString.data, catString.size, tmp.data+size);
    tmp.data[tmp.size] = 0;
    std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    size = tmp.size;
    return *this;
}
```